# Use same directive more than one time in same controller using same data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two hierarchical grid (using same directive) with same data in same controller. **But when I expand one grid, it also expand the other one.** I am using isolate scope.

```
 module.directive('treeGrid', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:'tree-grid-template.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          treeData: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          //logic
        }
    }
}]);

and html is :

<tree-grid tree-data="tree_data"></tree-data>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to provide your "`// logic`".

Comment: Check it here : http://khan4019.github.io/tree-grid-directive/test/treeGrid.html